# Spring cloud gateway redirection

Tags: java, spring-cloud, api-gateway

I have a simple requirement of replacing an old uri with a new one so that the clients can still make calls to the old uri

My API gateway is running on port 8090 and it's connected to Eureka server

Here's the property file in the gateway

```
spring.application.name=api-gateway-server
server.port=8090
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:9100/eureka

spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.enabled=true

spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.lower-case-service-id=true

logging.level.root=DEBUG
```

The old API via the gateway was

```
http://localhost:8090/currency-conversion-service/currency-convertor-feign/from/USD/to/INR/456
```

Where the 'currency-conversion-service' is the name of the destination application in Eureka

[image]

And the URI in the currency-conversion-service application has been changed to

```
/currency-convertor-v2/from/USD/to/INR/456
```

from

```
/currency-convertor-feign/from/USD/to/INR/456
```

So what I want is that when the clients hit the API gateway URL

```
http://localhost:8090/currency-conversion-service/currency-convertor-feign/from/USD/to/INR/456
```

The request is redirected to

```
/currency-convertor-v2/from/USD/to/INR/456
```

In the currency-conversion-service

And here's the code I was trying to write in the gateway application

```
package com.kingshuk.springcloudprojects.apigatewayserver;

import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.RouteLocator;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.builder.RouteLocatorBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class ApiRoutingConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public RouteLocator applicationRouteLocator(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
        return builder.routes()
                .route(p -> p.path("/currency-convertor-feign/**")
                        .filters(gatewayFilterSpec -> gatewayFilterSpec
                                .rewritePath("/currency-convertor-feign/(?<remaining>.*)"
                                , "/currency-convertor-v2/${remaining}}"))
                        .uri("http://currency-conversion-service/"))
                .build();
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work. Keep getting errors. No exception is printed in the API gateway logs as such.

I'm kind of new to the spring cloud gateway so would be great if I can get some help on this.

Thanks

Comment: lb://currency-conversion-service/

Comment: Have tried that...didn't work...but thanks for the response

Comment: you say "Keep getting errors", what errors? and "tried that... didn't work", what happened?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I didn't get any exceptions anywhere just that it didn't redirect and I got the whitelabel error page in the browser

Comment: What error code? What did the error page say?

Comment: 404 Not Found in the whitelabel error page

Comment: The path you want to hit starts with /currency-conversion-service/currency-convertor-feign/, but your path predicate doesn't include that

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out..!! let me try that out and let you know.

Comment: It works now....posting the code change in an answer that follows. Thanks a lot for your help....!!

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

It works now with the following code adjustments made as per suggestion by [spencergibb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2730527/spencergibb). Appreciate your help...!!

```
@Bean
    public RouteLocator applicationRouteLocator(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
        return builder.routes()
                .route(p -> p.path("/currency-conversion-service/currency-convertor-feign/**")
                        .filters(gatewayFilterSpec -> gatewayFilterSpec
                                .rewritePath("/currency-conversion-service/currency-convertor-feign/(?<remaining>.*)"
                                , "/currency-convertor-v2/${remaining}"))
                        .uri("lb://currency-conversion-service/"))
                .build();
    }
```